# Detecting UIButton tap for button inside of tappable view

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a container view with a button over it which hides and shows the view. Within the shown view, there are N number of mini buttons that have actions.

The problem I'm having is, when I tap on the mini buttons, those targets are ignored and the larger view button is what receives the action.

How do I configure things so that the larger tappable button on the view still works in most places but where the mini buttons exist, those tap actions register as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Why Do you still need a large button over containerView, When you had already added a subView That contains mini Buttons?

Comment: Because the user needs to be able to tap to show/hide the view most of the time but other times, they need to tap the smaller buttons to complete actions like showing a WKWebview

Comment: I will try to do this but I don't think using a button will work  still I will try to do it , How about using gestures on containerView instead of UIButton ?

Comment: There has to be a way to have a button within a button where both buttons work...

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solution
First

> Change view hierarchy of uibutton (large on top of the stack in
>   interface builder)

Like

**-Largebutton**

-minibutton1

-minibutton1

'
'

-minibuttonn

> Second one

Use **gesture** on the conainer view  like

```
    let hideViewGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideView")

    containerView.addGestureRecognizer(hideViewGesture)


func hideView() {
    containerView.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not merely possible to get button action working within a button as

1) Adding a button [Large button] on ContainerView will cause always to detect Large button action and will not allow you to detect button inside it

2) If seen in case of layers large button layer is on top So Logically always large button will first come in Action not inside View of containerView

Possible Solutions :

1) try to make use of gestures on ContainerView

2) you can use a segmented control as show and hide or a UIButton that is placed on side of containerView not over it So you will be able to perform all the required Actions

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but there actually is a simple solution, by overriding `hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?)`.

Inside your outer button:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.innerButton.frame.contains(point) {
        return self.innerButton
    }
    else if self.bounds.contains(point) {
        return self
    }
    else {
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

It tests to see if the touch point is within the inner button (or you could have several inner buttons), if so it returns it and the touch is registered only by the inner button, if not it goes to the outer view. If neither view contains it, it calls `super` so the touch is handled correctly by other views.